# Can someone explain to me like I'm 5 what this does?

Tags: python

Basically I was looking into keyboard imports and found this code sample regarding the pynput library.
Can someone explain what is going on here?

```py
def log_keystroke(key):
    key = str(key).replace("'", "")

    if key == 'Key.space':
        key = ' '
    if key == 'Key.shift_r':
        key = ''
    if key == "Key.enter":
        key = '\n'

    with open("log.txt", 'a') as f:
        f.write(key)

with Listener(on_press=log_keystroke) as l:
    l.join()
```

I understand this a keylogger of some sort, but I am most interested into knowing what is going on here:

```py
key = str(key).replace("'", "")
```

and here:

```py
with Listener(on_press=log_keystroke) as l:
    l.join()
```

Thanks for the help guys and girls!

Comment: Given a string, remove the `'` and then choose the correct action based on key type. Not sure what `Listener` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```py
with Listener(on_press=log_keystroke) as l:
    l.join()
```

creates a listener. This listener will "listen" for key presses. The `on_press=log_keystroke` tells the listener to give any keypresses it gets to `log_keystroke`. `l.join()` simply starts the listener. If you press a key it will send data about the key you pressed to `log_keystroke`. This is represented as a string. By default, the key name will have single quotes around it, like `'a'` or `'Key.enter'`. The single-quotes are *in* the string itself. `key = str(key).replace("'", "")` converts the key to a string and gets rid of the single-quotes.

Comment: Thanks, you answered everything perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is pynput.keyboard package. You will have all explanation in relative documentation : https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html